# Updating Meta Value doesn't work properly with serialized data in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization, woocommerce, metadata

I was wondering if someone could help with this. I'm trying to do a php query to update post meta values on Wordpress. Pb : the string has to be very long and full of unorthodox characters like double quotes.

The result is somewhat strange as it gets updated but adds another serial around the value, breaking it, like this :

s:5086:"**a:28:{i:0;a:7:.....**

Here's the initial query, if someone could figure out how to make it compliant that'd be amazing :

```
update_post_meta( $product_id, '_wc_booking_pricing', 'a:28:{i:0;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:5:"0.027";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"1";s:2:"to";s:1:"3";}i:1;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.02914814815";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"4";s:2:"to";s:1:"4";}i:2;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:12:"0.0312962963";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"5";s:2:"to";s:1:"5";}i:3;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.03344444444";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"6";s:2:"to";s:1:"6";}i:4;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.03559259259";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"7";s:2:"to";s:1:"7";}i:5;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.03774074074";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"8";s:2:"to";s:1:"8";}i:6;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.03988888889";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"9";s:2:"to";s:1:"9";}i:7;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.04203703704";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"10";s:2:"to";s:2:"10";}i:8;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.04418518519";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"11";s:2:"to";s:2:"11";}i:9;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.04633333333";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"12";s:2:"to";s:2:"12";}i:10;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.04848148148";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"13";s:2:"to";s:2:"13";}i:11;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.05062962963";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"14";s:2:"to";s:2:"14";}i:12;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.05277777778";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"15";s:2:"to";s:2:"15";}i:13;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.05492592593";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"16";s:2:"to";s:2:"16";}i:14;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.05707407407";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"17";s:2:"to";s:2:"17";}i:15;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.05922222222";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"18";s:2:"to";s:2:"18";}i:16;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.06137037037";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"19";s:2:"to";s:2:"19";}i:17;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.06351851852";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"20";s:2:"to";s:2:"20";}i:18;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.06566666667";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"21";s:2:"to";s:2:"21";}i:19;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.06781481481";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"22";s:2:"to";s:2:"22";}i:20;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.06996296296";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"23";s:2:"to";s:2:"23";}i:21;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.07211111111";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"24";s:2:"to";s:2:"24";}i:22;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.07425925926";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"25";s:2:"to";s:2:"25";}i:23;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.07640740741";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"26";s:2:"to";s:2:"26";}i:24;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.07855555556";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"27";s:2:"to";s:2:"27";}i:25;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:12:"0.0807037037";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"28";s:2:"to";s:2:"28";}i:26;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.08285185185";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"29";s:2:"to";s:2:"29";}i:27;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:5:"0.085";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"30";s:2:"to";s:2:"30";}}');
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing, but my gut instinct tells me you're doing it wrong!

Comment: Indeed, you are doing it wrong.  **Do not** serialize the data yourself first  - instead call `update_post_meta` and pass in the array / object / string that you want to save.  WP automatically serializes.  Then, when you use `get_post_meta`, WP automatically unserializes.

Comment: The reason for the double serialization is a security fix in WP that attempts to avoid deserializing untrusted data. You should probably follow the comments/answers that guide you to let WP handle serialization, and not do it manually.

Answer (score 3):

First, it's worth noting that you are not doing a PHP query, but rather you are using WordPress functions (update_post_meta) to save this data.  That is probably where the confusion lies.

The problem you are having is that you are passing in [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) data.  In WordPress, even though it stores the data in the DB as serialized data, you do not have to serialize / unserialize yourself.

WordPress stores the data serialized "automatically".  That means that when you call [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta), you should simply pass in the array you are trying to save.

This is a *minimal* example based on your code above:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'type' => 'blocks',
        'cost' => NULL,
        'modifier' => NULL,
        'base_cost' => 0.027,
        'base_modifier] => 'times',
        'from' => 1,
        'to' => 3
    ),
    array(
        'type' => 'blocks',
        'cost' => NULL,
        'modifier' => NULL,
        'base_cost' => 0.02914814815,
        'base_modifier] => 'times',
        'from] => 4,
        'to] => 4
    )
);

update_post_meta( $product_id, '_wc_booking_pricing', $data );
```

Then, when you *retreive* the data using [get_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), it will return it *as an array*, exactly as you saved it.

Comment: Good to note internally get_post_meta() calls get_metadata() which calls get_metadata_raw() that then runs maybe_unserialize().  update_post_meta() calls meta.php::update_metadata() which runs maybe_serialize()

Answer (score 3):

The string that you are trying to pass through [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) is **serialized data** and needs first to be unserialized.

**Two possible cases:**

**1) If you have serialize that data**, just don't do it and pass the data **array** directly in `update_post_meta()`.

> Note that a *"passed array will be serialized into a string"* when using `update_post_meta()`, so in your case to avoid a kind of double serialization that will make your data **unreadable**.

**2) If you have not serialize that data** yourself, you might need to unserialize this data first. For that you can use the WordPress function [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) before using `update_post_meta()`, this way:

```
// Unserializing the data
$data = maybe_unserialize( 'a:28:{i:0;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:5:"0.027";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"1";s:2:"to";s:1:"3";}i:1;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.02914814815";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"4";s:2:"to";s:1:"4";}i:2;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:12:"0.0312962963";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"5";s:2:"to";s:1:"5";}i:3;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.03344444444";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"6";s:2:"to";s:1:"6";}i:4;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.03559259259";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"7";s:2:"to";s:1:"7";}i:5;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.03774074074";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"8";s:2:"to";s:1:"8";}i:6;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.03988888889";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:1:"9";s:2:"to";s:1:"9";}i:7;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.04203703704";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"10";s:2:"to";s:2:"10";}i:8;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.04418518519";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"11";s:2:"to";s:2:"11";}i:9;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.04633333333";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"12";s:2:"to";s:2:"12";}i:10;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.04848148148";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"13";s:2:"to";s:2:"13";}i:11;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.05062962963";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"14";s:2:"to";s:2:"14";}i:12;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.05277777778";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"15";s:2:"to";s:2:"15";}i:13;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.05492592593";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"16";s:2:"to";s:2:"16";}i:14;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.05707407407";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"17";s:2:"to";s:2:"17";}i:15;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.05922222222";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"18";s:2:"to";s:2:"18";}i:16;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.06137037037";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"19";s:2:"to";s:2:"19";}i:17;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.06351851852";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"20";s:2:"to";s:2:"20";}i:18;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.06566666667";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"21";s:2:"to";s:2:"21";}i:19;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.06781481481";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"22";s:2:"to";s:2:"22";}i:20;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.06996296296";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"23";s:2:"to";s:2:"23";}i:21;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.07211111111";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"24";s:2:"to";s:2:"24";}i:22;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.07425925926";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"25";s:2:"to";s:2:"25";}i:23;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.07640740741";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"26";s:2:"to";s:2:"26";}i:24;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.07855555556";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"27";s:2:"to";s:2:"27";}i:25;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:12:"0.0807037037";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"28";s:2:"to";s:2:"28";}i:26;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:13:"0.08285185185";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"29";s:2:"to";s:2:"29";}i:27;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"blocks";s:4:"cost";s:0:"";s:8:"modifier";s:0:"";s:9:"base_cost";s:5:"0.085";s:13:"base_modifier";s:5:"times";s:4:"from";s:2:"30";s:2:"to";s:2:"30";}}' );

// Saving the data
update_post_meta( $product_id, '_wc_booking_pricing', $data );
```

Now your data is correctly saved in database and can be read and/or processed.

Comment: Great tip about WP's `maybe_unserialize`.  That's a super-handy function - I've actually ported it to other non-WP projects I've used.

Comment: Thanks @cale_b… *( `get_post_meta()` uses `maybe_unserialize()` and  `update_post_meta()` use `maybe_serialize()` )*… I think that this Op is kind off loosed.

Comment: Thanks, Your answer helped me @LoicTheAztec There is no need to serialize data while updating meta. It will be done automatically if needed.